# mdadm - What's the difference between --detail --scan and --examine --scan?

Tags: raid, mdadm

From `man mdadm`:

```
-E, --examine
  Print  contents  of  the  metadata  stored on the named device(s).  Note the 
  contrast between --examine and --detail.  --examine applies to devices which 
  are components of an array, while --detail applies to a whole array which is 
  currently active.
```

This statement is quite mysterious... On my system, the output of `--examine --scan` and `--detail --scan` seems to be identical. The only differences are:

1. `--detail` must be executed as root
2. different position of the `name` entry

Maybe in other systems the output can be different. So what's the difference between `--examine --scan` and `--detail --scan` and which is more useful for generating `mdadm.conf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `man` page information indicates `--detail` applies to

a whole array which is currently active
That "currently active" is the important part. `--examine` can be used on devices that are parts of a RAID, or on non-active RAIDs, whereas `--detail` cannot.

If you have the chance, stop your array and retry both `--examine` and `--detail` to compare the difference.